# Отказывается работать focus

Tags: css

```
 td :  focus{
     border:2px solid #C00;
background:none;
background-color:#069;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прямо так и говорит - "отказываюсь работать"? :-)

А если серьёзно - псевдо-класс :focus применим к элементам, которые могут получить фокус (`<a>, <input>, <select> и <textarea>`)

Для td попробуйте :hover

Comment: hover тоже отказывается.

Comment: Радик, а с ховером вы так же кучу пробелов между элементом, двоеточием и псевдоклассом ставите, да?

Comment: Спасибо!
Только оказывается это не подходит. Мне надо на нажатие затемнение, и оставить так даже после того как будет убран фокус с элемента.

Answer (score 0):

```
td:focus{
  border: #C00 2px solid;
  background: #069;
}
```

> Мне надо на нажатие затемнение, и оставить так даже после того как будет убран фокус с элемента.

JQuery:

```
$('td').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

И прописывайте стили для `td.clicked`;

Comment: Добавил "по клику".

Comment: Спасибо!
А есть такая функция, чтобы если нажал на другой td , то с предыдущего класс автоматически удалялся? Или ручками все прописывать??

Comment: аналогично:

    $('td').click(function() {
      $('td').removeClass('clicked');
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });

Comment: спасибо!
Про removeClass я и имел ввиду, когда говорил "ручками все прописывать", просто думал может какая-нить автоматическая функция есть.

Comment: Ваще народ обленился)) Ручками - это выловить все td, отфильтровать регуляркой по классу, заменить класс, а потом присвоить текущей) jquery развращает, однако.